# correct password; but it will not open my account

Tags: 14.04, login

I started up my ubuntu and it lead to a login prompt. I input the correct password for the account. It went to a black screen for a flash, but it made the default "bongo" error sound and aborted back to the same prompt. No error was displayed.

I know this is the right password, because inputting any other password will make the prompt say "Invalid Login". Only the correct password causes the error.

Also, on that note, my account is set to automatic login.

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Can you login to the terminal? Press `Ctrl-Alt-F2` to get to one, and try.

Comment: @Tim, sometimes F1 has log messages hiding the prompt (or causing it to not show up).

Comment: I was able to login using control-alt-f2 and using that prompt. I simply added a new user with new privileges as a cheap way around the problem. It seemed to say there was a `KeyError` in the cache or something

Answer (score 0):

From the info that you have provided it seems to me that there might be an issue with the display manager, it seems the display manager could not start your session or load the desktop environment.

There might also be an issue with the permission of the `/tmp` folder (happened in my case).

Comment: I have the same problem. I login in F1 or F2 to reinstasll xorg, but same problem. What is Muru's suggestion you mentioned?

Comment: @hakunami: The suggestion was **"Can you login to the terminal? Press Ctrl-Alt-F2 to get to one, and try."** ..note that you should ask a new question so that others can also help you..

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. `sudo rm /home/(username)/.Xauth*`
3. restart `lightdm`
4. back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had done `chmod 555` to my `/home` folder which created the problem. The solution is to change the permissions back by using someone else's laptop.

1. do `ssh (your laptop username)@(your IP)`
2. enter password(here u will be able to log in because you are accessing via terminal)
3. cd ..
4. `chmod 755 (your username on laptop)`

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: SSH is not default-installed on laptops; the OP makes no indication that they have SSH, therefore this answer may not help future readers.

Comment: Press Ctrl-ALT-F1 for a local terminal, there is no need to do this remote

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by deleting the file.I created using the same method above, just substitute the filename. I created a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d` and then reboot, the problem comes here.